# What are these brown boxes, found near the north-east coast of Japan used for?

Tags: japan, identify-this

I stumbled across a small Japanese village (in Higashidori, Aomori) whilst playing GeoGuessr.

Along the main road you can find this brown boxes, they are elevated slightly above ground and have green curved roofs. They appear to have sliding doors but I can't see anything inside them.

The exact location for the box below can be found [here](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@41.1386717,141.3912565,3a,40.9y,40.93h,86.25t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1spRnWmvwoge0xG_wR6Ctflw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en&shorturl=1).

[image]

If you follow the road, you can find more boxes with the same design. They are close enough that you can sometimes see the other box from where you are standing. They can be found on both sides of the road and go from the coast up to the hills.

On the front of each box is a notice, but I'm unable to read the text.

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, would they work as changing room for those wanting to use the beach?

Comment: @Willeke I thought so too but they're quite short and some of them are more remote. [This particular one](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@41.1296044,141.392661,3a,75y,186.67h,91.25t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sEAKzc7_XmTcsujOI5i6K4w!2e0!7i13312!8i6656?hl=en) is over a kilometre away from the coast.

Comment: @Willeke,I wouldn't change in there - you can easily see the inside. But I'm not Japanese.

Comment: @fkraiem What makes this question more off-topic than every other [identify-this] question?

Comment: The description of [identify-this] reads: "Finding the name of some place, food, monument, or other *travel-related* thing." (Emphasis added.)

Comment: @fkraiem Could you explain [how the highest voted question with this tag](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100716/what-are-these-large-empty-towers-made-of-connected-metal-girders-bars-or-pipe) is any different?

Comment: @fkraiem I'd suggest taking this to meta so a community-wide policy can be established.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I finally found one of these boxes that had clear enough text.

It looks like these boxes are called **[ごみ収集ステーション](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E3%81%94%E3%81%BF%E5%8F%8E%E9%9B%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJlpf4u_PWAhWCWRoKHdhVBkIQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=949)** which translated is 'Garbage Collection Station'.

It looks like the notice is also describing different types of waste and explaining how they are sorted. Perhaps collections are picked up on different days depending on their type.

According to [this](https://www.tokyo-icc.jp/guide_eng/info/01.html) website for foreign residents living in Japan, bagged trash must be taken to a designated pickup point.

Comment: It's common in Japan for cans, glass, plastic bottles, burnable trash, and non-burnable trash to be picked up on different days; in Tokyo, you can find both enclosures like this (though they're more likely to be plastic or metal) or just marked collection points on the street due to space constraints. Different cities often have different collection days, which adds a bit of a "gotcha" to moving between them. It can be quite complex; this page is for [Shinjuku](http://www.foreign.city.shinjuku.lg.jp/en/seikatsu/seikatsu_2/)
 ([PDF](http://www.city.shinjuku.lg.jp/content/000193711.pdf)).

Comment: Any idea why it's written "こみ" rather than "ごみ"? Is that a regional thing, or something?

Comment: You can just barely make it out in the picture but the third column shows which day it's picked up.

Comment: @EthanKaminski I asked on the Japanese SE about that: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53834/18189

Comment: @muru ah, good idea!

Comment: @EthanKaminski I answered [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53838/25446) that it's likely a typographical error.

Comment: @keithmaxx I couldn't find any more boxes that showed the dakuten but I've added it to the answer because it seems much more common with.

Comment: @kungphu Not just in Japan, a lot of places in Western Europe also have garbage collection. This also happens in multiple ways: there are special glass collection stations all over Belgium, garbage is collected every week, non-glass food and drink containers every 2 weeks, cardboard and paper also every 2 weeks and a couple of smaller things every month. There is also a special area in each municipality where tons of things can be deposited, from asbestos and construction waste to styrofoam and all kinds of metals.

Comment: @Nzall I wasn't suggesting that this was unique to Japan, just giving the answer some extra relevant context.